# Is there an NPC who can repair to 100% in Fallout 3?

Tags: fallout-3

Is there an NPC someplace in Fallout 3, or the expansions, who can repair the unique items (Chinese stealth armor, etc) to 100%?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to the Fallout 3 Wiki -- [Somah](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Somah) (An NPC from the Mothership Zeta DLC) has a repair skill of 100.

You may also look into [Haley](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Haley) (An NPC from the Point Lookout DLC) who has a glitch that will eventually bring his repair skill up to 100.

If you are just looking to repair your unique items up to 100%, look into [Alien Epoxy](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Alien_Epoxy), a semi-repeatably obtainable consumable that instantly restores between 15% and 30% condition to an item. (Also from the Mothership Zeta DLC)

Comment: The Alien Epoxy link has changed, the new one is: http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Alien_epoxy

Answer (score 0):

Just letting you know, Chinese Stealth Armor can be repaired with Recon Armor. However, you will need to use the aforementioned techniques to repair the Gauss Rifle. In addition, I am pretty sure that the Winter Armor does not degrade (which is honestly a little odd).

Comment: I believe the Winter Armor does degrade.  However, there's a bug (shocking, I know!) that winds up with you getting the simulation version of the armor instead of the one the developers intended, so the armor has a ridiculous amount of durability.  The regular degradation rate barely makes a dent in it as a result.